# C# MongoDB Driver: Can I use generic type for BsonId?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

I had a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [BsonId]
    public Guid MyId { get; private set; }
    // some other properties...

    [BsonConstructor]
    public MyClass(Guid id)
    {
        MyId = id;
        // set some other properties...
    }
}
```

This recently refactored some things.  The code above has a series of tests covering it, which all passed before the refactor.  Now I have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    [BsonId]
    public T MyId { get; private set; }
    // some other properties...

    [BsonConstructor]
    public MyClass(T id)
    {
        MyId = id;
        // set some other properties...
    }
}
```

The hope was that the old code can work the same as it did before, using `MyClass<Guid>` and serializing so that each document would have an _id like a Guid, and that the new code could use a new object,
like `MyClass<NewIdType>` and serialize to a compound key like _id: { guid, integer }.  The new id class looks like:

```
public class NewIdType
{
    public Guid NewId { get; set; }
    public int NewIdRank { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know enough about how serialization works.  I have seen many examples (none exactly like this...) and been through the [Serialization Tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/), with no success.

For what its worth, the old set of tests will pass with `MyClass<Guid>`, so it seems I am allowed to have a BsonId with a generic type.  But the test fail for `MyClass<NewIdType>` with an exception
of "NewIdType cannot be mapped to BsonValue".

Am I missing something simple, or am I just not allowed to have a BsonId of a generic type like this?

Comment: Interesting. Probably just a use case never encountered. Please file a bug at jira.mongodb.com under the CSHARP project.

Comment: I have used a generic type base class in production, never had a problem. Just threw the OP's example in, works fine. Are you maybe mixing up old and new documents in the same collection, such that you're trying, at some point, to read and `int` from a database document that has a `NewIdType`-id?

Comment: So, this problem is finally resolved, and @mnemosyn is correct, everything works fine.  The problem was in the call to `MongoCollection(TDefaultDocument).FindOneByIdAs`.  Since I am no longer only finding Guids, I needed to change it to use FindOneAs, and use a Query.

Comment: Just on the administrative front: What should I do with this question?  Technically there is nothing wrong, but it was @mnemosyn comment (about everything working fine for him) that led me to STOP investigating that path, and start checking out where I was using it.  May still be useful for someone?

Comment: I'd suggest you post an answer to your own question where you briefly describe the solution, that should help for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem. The refactored class from the problem statement works fine.

The problem was not with the generic type as as a BsonId, or with the serialization of the new class, but with existing method calls.

A series of tests used the method `MongoCollection(TDefaultDocument).FindOneByIdAs`. When the refactor was complete, this code still built, but since we were no longer finding only Guids, it threw the exception described in the problem statement.

I changed the tests to use `MongoCollection(TDefaultDocument).FindOneAs`, using a new Query to check the UID, and everything works as expected now.